# Add Shipping Address after add the product to Cart for all Customers

Tags: quote, shipping-address, estimate

I added the Shipping price, Subtotal and Grand Total to the Mini Cart.
So that the customers can check their shipping price in the Mini Cart.
I think the magento is stored the shipping price in Quote Object.
And the Quote object is created after the product to the Cart.
So I tried to add the shipping address(zipcode, regioncode, city) to the Quote Object.
And I get the shipping address(zipcode, regioncode, city) from the customer IP.
But it's not working.

Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
        <plugin name="plugin_name" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart" sortOrder="20" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

Vendor\Module\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart.php

```
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data as CheckoutHelper;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

public function afterGetSectionData(
        \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        //Set quote shipping address
        $ipData = $this->miniHelper->getIPData();

        if (!$this->customerCart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()) {

            $this->customerCart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
                ->setCountryId('US')
                ->setCity($ipData['city'])
                ->setPostcode($ipData['zipCode'])
                ->setRegionId($ipData['regionCode'])
                ->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        }

        $this->quoteRepository->save($this->customerCart->getQuote());
$shippingCost = $this->customerCart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount();
$result['shipping_cost'] = isset($shippingCost) ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($shippingCost) : 0;

return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a function call I found in the CartController::indexAction function.
$cart->init(); will set the cart's status to CHECKOUT_STATE_BEGIN and clear all associated addresses. So it needs to be called before getting the address objects.
Such as:

```
if((isset($params['territory_value_submitted']) && !empty($params['territory_value_submitted']))) {
      $cart->init();

      $shipping_address = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
      $billing_address = $cart->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
```

Now changes made to the addresses won't be cleared out by $cart->init() being called on the cart page
Also, the correct shipping methods could not be chosen without setting the CountryId for the shipping address. Since I only ship within the US all my shipping rules were restricted to the US and no matching rules were found.
This was fixed by changing
$shipping_address
->setCountryId('US')